# Problemas con traer un script a un pdf The html tag [script] is not known by Html2Pdf

Tags: php, javascript, html2pdf

Necesito traer unas graficas hechas en JS a un PDF para mandarlo como reporte, pero el tag script no lo reconoce el html2pdf, no se que hacer, ya he intentado varias cosas

> The html tag [script] is not known by Html2Pdf

Comment: _PHP_ y _Html2PDF_ no pueden interpretar código _javascript_, tal vez podrías probar a generarlo desde el navegador con [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: Entiendo... Ya lo probare, gracias. Deja tu respuesta oficial y te marco